# How to make session cookies persist in requests?

Tags: session-cookies, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle in the frontend and I need to use the $_SESSION from my API response.
I am successfully using cookies in my requests, but I can't get the session cookies to persist in the browser session. On each request, the PHPSESID is reset.

I've been reading the [documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies)  about Cookies, but I can't make the GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SessionCookieJar class to work.

This is how I manage my requests client:

```
//Guzzle Client
        $headers = array( //Headers default
            "Authorization" => 'Bearer '.$this->access_token,
            "Accept" => "application/json"
        );
        
        $this->guzzle_config = array(
            'base_uri' => $this->base_uri,
            'headers' => $headers,
            'verify' => false,
            'cookies' => true
        );
$this->cookie_jar = CookieJar::fromArray([
            "mycookiename" => "mycookievalue"
        ], "www.mydomain.com";
        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client($this->guzzle_config);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've tried to set persistent Session Cookies according to the Guzzle documentation.